# Deserializing binary files in a Visual Studio AddIn - 'Could not find assembly'

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, serialization, reflection

I've created a Visual Studio (2010) AddIn, and decided to go for a binary serialized file to store my settings. It turns out that when deserializing the file, I get a 'Could not find assembly MyAddin.xxx' exception.

I could only assume this is the result of the AddIn assembly being loaded into a different domain than the one which created the serialized file. I've tried to stream the file into AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory (which is the Visual Studio folder in Program Files), as well as the Addins folder in My Documents where the original assembly resides, but still to no avail.

Could someone please provide some insight as to what is happening and how to get around the problem?

Comment: Please post the exact wording of the exception.

Comment: Unable to find assembly 'AfrigleReleaseManagerAddin, Version=1.0.4975.36203, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.

Comment: The problem isn't the assembly version incrementing either, because I serialize and attempt to deserialize in the same instance, same problem.

Comment: You no doubt have a problem with the probing path for devenv.exe.  Without knowing where you put files, use Fuslogvw.exe to see the bind fail and where the CLR looked for the assembly.

Comment: @HansPassant I tried that, all I got was a fail with /Common7/IDE/StanPackage.DLL. No idea what that is.